# Qt platform plugin "windows"

Tags: 16.04, wine, qt

While installing a Windows application using Wine 
I'm getting this error message:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows"
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem
```

Comment: `Reinstalling the application may fix this problem` : is this from you or part of the error message

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen That's from the message - I've seen this message as well.